# Why does Maven Jetty Plugin not find a class in a standard jetty jar

Tags: jetty, maven-3, noclassdeffounderror, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm using Jetty 9.0.4v20130625 running it using the `maven-jetty-plugin`. I have implemented my own `LoginService` class to handle users logging in to a realm. On one of the lines, I attempt to use the `org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Credential` class but during execution it throws a `NoClassDefFoundError` on that line.

My `target` directory contains everything being deployed to the Jetty instance. Within it the `WEB-INF/lib` folder does not contain the `jetty-util-9.0.4.v20130625.jar` as expected because the plugin should already have it so I believe that rules out conflicting jars. So what could be causing the jetty instance to not find this jar?

I am using eclipse, and it shows no errors in the code. I set it up as a Maven project and Maven handles the dependencies. I set it to not to package the jetty jars as they should be provided by Jetty when deployed. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project ...>
  ...
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.4.v20130625</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>...</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.4.v20130625</version>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <webApp>
            <contextPath>/...</contextPath>
          </webApp>
          <login-config>
            <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
            <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
            <form-login-config>
              <form-login-page>/loginAuth.html?param=redirect</form-login-page>
              <form-error-page>/loginAuth.html?param=failed</form-error-page>
            </form-login-config>
          </login-config>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <connectionType>developerConnection</connectionType>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <ant target="deploy" />
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.50</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I checked to be sure the plugin depends on the jetty-util.jar and it does as seen [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/9.0.4.v20130625)

Something that may be part of the problem: To implement a new `LoginService` interface class, I am extending the `MappedLoginService` class which already implements `LoginService` (it's in the Jetty jars) and I'm overriding some of its methods. Could that be causing a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty hides almost all of its implementation classes from the webapp's classloader. If you need access to them from inside your webapp, then you need to put them into your webapp's WEB-INF/lib (in your case add a dependency for jetty-util jar).

This classloading mechanism is described here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-classloading.html

BTW, the configuration for the jetty-maven-plugin from your pom.xml seems to contain some lines from web.xml (i.e. those inside the  elements). I believe maven ignores configuration it doesn't understand, but perhaps things are not configured the way you think they are? Also, I don't see any setup for using your custom LoginService.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jan. I thought that might be the case. About your suggestion to add a dependency for jetty-util.jar--If I put jetty-util.jar inside my lib folder, I get a loader constraint violation. The error says the org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm class loader and ...jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader have different objects for the type ...jetty.util.security.Credential.  I take it that I will have to manually import the Credential class and any other jetty dependencies I have into my project under a different package? Is that correct?

Comment: About the plugin configuration: you are right, login-config was unnecessary. I saw it included in some other examples somewhere, but my web.xml includes the login-config as well and it is working fine. Also, I didn't bother putting the configuration for the custom loginService on here because I know it is configured correctly--it executes code in my class when it should, but fails on Credential. Including the jetty-util.jar in the lib causes a LinkageError described in my last comment.

Comment: It sounds as if you have your custom LoginService effectively inside of your war. I don't think that will fly, as a LoginService is part of the container's artifacts. I would recommend you make a separate project for the customized LoginService, then add its jar to the jetty-maven-plugin dependencies - that way everything is on the container's classpath.